# Design-time DataContext in a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, datatemplate, datacontext, designer

When I put a `DataTemplate` in a `<Page.Resources>` section, it inherits the `DataContext` of the `Page` when editing bindings inside the designer. However at run-time the `DataTemplate` is being used by an element inside the `Page` which has its own `DataContext`. I want the designer to show the inner `DataContext` while binding instead.

Is there a tag like `d:DataContext` for `DataTemplates`? Setting `DataType` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found you can just set `d:DataContext` on the root element inside the `DataTemplate`.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Height}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: The Type parameter is unnecessary because it's part of the default constructor if you omit it.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is super old but for the sake of making SO better.  DataTemplates have a "DataContext" through the DataType tag.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Height}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```